# Adding 1 Day to date string in (MM/DD/YY) formal mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add one day to my column that in format of mm/dd/yyyy but its giving me null output for newdate

date1 = 27/03/2019

```
SELECT date1,DATE_ADD(CONCAT(date1," 00:00:00") , INTERVAL 1 DAY) as newdate FROM table1 WHERE =id ="00056"
```

Comment: Are your dates stored as text?

Comment: Store your date as a `DATE` column type, which is `YYYY-MM-DD` in [ISO-8601 form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). You can always convert as necessary for display in whatever locale uses that ambiguous form.

Answer (score 0):

If your `date1` column stores dates as text in the form "27/03/2019" then you can use

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(date1,"%d/%m/%Y"), INTERVAL 1 DAY) as newdate ...
```

Comment: Close but you have to convert it back.

Comment: @tadman The OP's query does not attempt to store the modified date back into the database. Maybe the OP could clarify the intent a bit more.